# Laravel elastic search Update Index

Tags: php, json, laravel, elasticsearch

**1)My first question is**:
In Laravel project when I run the command as 
"PHP artisan elastic:update-index JKIndexConfigurator"
It gives error as " Class 'JKIndexConfigurator' not found " 
though the class is available.

**Question 2**: as I add mappings in my index configurator as below mappings:

```
protected $defaultMapping = [
    'properties' => [
        `text` => [
             'type'   => 'text',
                 'fields' => [
                    'raw'   => [
                         'type'  => 'text',
                         'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                   ], 
                       'updated_at' => [
                       'type'       => 'text',
                           'fielddata' => true,
                       ],
                   ],
                ],
             ],
        ];
```

Then it gives error as :

> "Field data is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [updated_at] in order to load field data in memory by un-inverting the inverted index. Note that this can, however, uses significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead. [reason: all shards failed]"

-I have added the mapping in index configurator
-delete index
-created index
-import models by command "PHP artisan scout: import "App\Model\JobPost"

the same error displayed.
what should I do???